# Folder wil open a PHP file

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have Apache (2.4) running on my Mac. But something weird happens.

I activated `mod_users`, when I navigate to `/localhost/~myname`, I see my empty folder.

When I create a php file called register.php and navigate to `/localhost/~myname/register.php` I see my PHP file, but when I go to `/localhost/~myname/register` I see the same PHP file.

I dont have a htacces, so its not mod_rewrite related.

A $_SERVER var dump:

```
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
string(16) "/~myname/register"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(20) "/~myname/register.php"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
string(20) "/~myname/register.php"
```

As you can see, my REQUEST_URI is different from my SCRIPT_NAME.

My httpd.conf: http://pastebin.com/sKzHpS9B

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: have you activated php in your apache installation?

Comment: As you can see in my httpd.conf yes, as you can see i posted a $_SERVER dump. I think that is impossible without PHP, so yes my PHP is activated!

Comment: Not sure.  Might look at the `conf` files in `/private/etc/apache2/extra/` also.

Comment: I cant find anything in the extra folder that cracks my mind about this problem..

Comment: Also I would try to remove the `<IfModule mod_php5.c>` totally and maybe try not use the bundle php

Comment: Tried it, still the same!